# TFS to VisualStudio Online Migration - Error occurred while sync: For input string: ""

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying out the new Visual Studio Online Migration Utility and setup a version control migration from an on premise TFS2010 team project to a Visual Studio Online project. I completed the migration configuration successfully. I started the migration and it completed the Reading and Analysis phase without any error.

The migration step, however, stops after processing a number of change sets / labels. There is now one change set pending for retry. When I go to the details of the failure I see the following:

```
Changeset ID : LabelType_Entity@@2257@@7870
Error        : OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. For input string: ""
```

Is there any way to figure out what this error message means? This is the error information I found in the OpsHub.log file.

```
05/19/2014 10:07:29,043 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1400486849042.txt
05/19/2014 10:07:29,044 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1400486849043.txt
05/19/2014 10:07:32,307 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1400486852306.txt
05/19/2014 10:07:32,466 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] (org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement) - action threw exception: script evaluation exception
org.jbpm.graph.def.DelegationException: script evaluation exception
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:139)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:73)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.execute(Script.java:62)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeAction(GraphElement.java:259)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeActions(GraphElement.java:215)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireAndPropagateEvent(GraphElement.java:185)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireEvent(GraphElement.java:169)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Transition.take(Transition.java:138)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.leave(Node.java:393)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:192)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:140)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.signal(ProcessInstance.java:270)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeTask(ProcessEngine.java:102)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeProcess(ProcessEngine.java:44)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.syncEvent(SyncEaiProcess.java:200)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.sync(SyncEaiProcess.java:125)
    at com.opshub.eai.OIMEventGenerator.process(OIMEventGenerator.java:247)
    at com.opshub.jobs.core.OHJob.execute(OHJob.java:87)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: com.opshub.eai.core.exceptions.OIMSCMAdapterException: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. For input string: ""
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:365)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHVariableDeclarator.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHTypedVariableDeclaration.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:130)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.findDestinationCommitIdForGlobalId(OIMSCMAdapter.java:411)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:209)
    ... 34 more
05/19/2014 10:07:32,470 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] (com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess) - Error in executing process definition : SCM Default Integration Workflow at node callMethod
OpsHub-012013: Process execution failed on node: callMethod, in process definition: 'SCM Default Integration Workflow'; nested exception is : script evaluation exception
com.opshub.exceptions.eai.EAIProcessEngineException: OpsHub-012013: Process execution failed on node: callMethod, in process definition: 'SCM Default Integration Workflow'; nested exception is : script evaluation exception
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeTask(ProcessEngine.java:116)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeProcess(ProcessEngine.java:44)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.syncEvent(SyncEaiProcess.java:200)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.sync(SyncEaiProcess.java:125)
    at com.opshub.eai.OIMEventGenerator.process(OIMEventGenerator.java:247)
    at com.opshub.jobs.core.OHJob.execute(OHJob.java:87)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: org.jbpm.graph.def.DelegationException: script evaluation exception
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:139)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:73)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.execute(Script.java:62)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeAction(GraphElement.java:259)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeActions(GraphElement.java:215)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireAndPropagateEvent(GraphElement.java:185)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireEvent(GraphElement.java:169)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Transition.take(Transition.java:138)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.leave(Node.java:393)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:192)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:140)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.signal(ProcessInstance.java:270)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeTask(ProcessEngine.java:102)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.opshub.eai.core.exceptions.OIMSCMAdapterException: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. For input string: ""
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:365)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHVariableDeclarator.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHTypedVariableDeclaration.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:130)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.findDestinationCommitIdForGlobalId(OIMSCMAdapter.java:411)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:209)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: This is defect in OpsHub Migration Utility, we will provide new build with resolution for this in near future.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in version 1.0.1.006 
You can download it latest release from here.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2/file/132237/5/OVSMU-V1.0.1.006.exe